# Is CSRF/Honeypot enough to reduce spamming on contact forms - I think I want a spam bot?

Tags: forms, captcha, csrf, spam, honeypot

I'm looking to reduce "spammy" submissions of contact/product enquiry forms.

While Google's ReCaptcha is good, it is quite hard to use at times as the captcha image can be far from identifiable and other captcha methods suffer the same problem.

In the last few weeks, I've had pretty good results with just CSRF/Honeypot techniques, but I understand that CSRF will only stop the "dumbest" bots that scrape a page for form fields and POST directly.

I'd love to play with the actual tools that get used to generate spam. Does anyone know of a few good popular examples?

Many thanks in advance!